# zip arrays de diferente longitud en ruby

Tags: array, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo lo siguientes arrays de ejemplo:

> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>
> b = [1,2]
>
> c = [1,2,3]

Quisiera poder zipear los array para que me devuelva algo como lo siguiente:

> array_final = [ [1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,1,3],[4,2,1],[5,1,2] ]

Lo que he intentado hasta ahora es lo siguiente, pero aqui pierdo de completar valores cuando los array son de diferente longitud:

> a.zip(b, c)   #=> [ [1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,nil,3],[4,nil,nil],[5,nil,nil] ]

Lo que necesito en el caso anterior es que en vez de que el valor sea 'nil', inicie de nuevo el array que corresponde para que le asigne un valor.

Comment: Lo que describes no es la funcionalidad zip de ruby, así que deberías implementar algo por cuenta propia que vuelva a reiterar sobre el resto de arreglos

Comment: Muchas gracias @AlterLagos , se te ocurre algo que pueda hacer para obtener lo deseado?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esto:

```
a.zip(b, c).map{|ar| ar.compact}
```

Al hacer compact en cada elemento del array superior eliminas los elementos a nil.

Comment: Agrega una explicación del porque de tu respuesta, con esto ayudas a que otras personas con el mismo problema puedan resolverlo y entender como es que funciona tu respuesta.

Comment: Espero que ahora se entienda mejor